# A small black square appears on my screen after toggling off desktop effects in OpenSUSE 13.2

Tags: opensuse, desktop-environment

It blocks mouse click on what it covers, and sometimes follow my input cursor.

Desktop environment is KDE.

My graphic card is Intel Mobile 915 family and my laptop is Lenovo X200s.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's my sogou pinyin IME used for inputing Chinese.

No wonder why only I am experiencing this problem.